Attach stairs to slanted concrete retaining wall
I have existing stairs leaning against a retaining wall that are falling apart and I would like to replace them. The stringers are built out of 2x12 lumber and the stairs as well. I know that those stairs are technically too steep, but I am ok with this.

My concern is that they are just leaning against the wall and I would like to raise the wood from the concrete for two reasons: No direct contact with the ground and added safety to it cannot fall over.
I was thinking of attaching fence post bases to the retaining wall and then attaching the stringers to those post bases. The problem is that those only exist in 4x4 and I wasn't able to find any that are U-shaped in 2 inch width. I was thinking of doubling the 2x12 in those places so they would fit.

Would this be ok? Are there any other good ways of doing this?
Here are the post bases I was planning on using:


How is the existing staircase (ladder) attached to the wall?

A few micro suggestions: drag the bottom of the stringer out a few feet to ease the angle and use your post base on the bottom of the stringer. And maybe look at ’alternating tread stairs’. If your friends/ family are the litigious types, you might consider a handrail or two.

Special order, probably, but Simpson “ABA Adjustable Post Base ( ABA24-2Z )“ holds 2-2x properly.

What you have in mind will work fine. You will not need to use a doubled 2X12, the second member to add could be 2x4 pressure treated along with the other pressure treated material.
Simply secure the 2X4 to the 2X12 with approved screws for contact with pressure treated wood and you are set. About 8 or 10 screws per side will hold.
You could also use a narrower tread, like 2X8s so there will be room to add the 2X4 behind them without too much extra cutting.
I made a loft ladder with 2X8 treads and it was very comfortable going up and down.

Thank you for the response, I appreciate it. With the 2x8, are you suggesting to "flip" the 2x4 so that it fills out the post base and then add the 2x8 on top of that so that the total is "L"-shaped?

Not quite, use the 2X12 for the sides just like the original, but instead of 2X12 treads, use 2X8s, hold them to the front edge of the sides,. That will leave room to add a 2X4 on the insides of each side of the 2X12s to make them wide enough to fit in the post clip better. It would be small still but the metal clip can move that much. Your idea about adding it to the bottom of the sides, using 2X10s for everything (I know I mentioned 2X8s, but that was to make room for the added 2X4) That way it will fill the clip, and the 2X10 with the 2X4 flat under it will be no higher than the original.

I might ask, how were you planning on setting the post anchors in the concrete? May I also add that the sides could run up an extra 2 or 3 feet to act as an aid stepping above grade. That part could be added, or use longer 2X12s and cut the top that goes on higher, down to a 2X4 or 2X3 dimension.

I was planning on using 1/2 inch wedge concrete anchors, the ones that have a hex nut on top and expand at the bottom when tightened. Tension and sheer strength seems to be more than sufficient for this purpose. I realized that doubling up a 2x12 with a 2x4 only gets me 3 inch, not 3 1/2 inch as the bases are designed for.

Cool, the wedge anchors will work very well for you here. The 2X4 flat will get you where you need to go.for the width too if you choose to go that way. I was suggesting 2X10s for everything since it should be cheaper than 2X12s and will be as strong as it ever would need to be. Nailing or screwing the 2X4 on the back is a good way to go too
